# Change of address tool couldn't fetch the page error

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, change-address-tool

We migrated from `https://example.org` to `https://example.com`.It seems we have done all requirements mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9370220?hl=en&authuser=1#prerequisites) for using search console change of address tool but now it has passed 4 days from our migration and still every time I try to use the change of address tool after pressing 'VALIDATE & UPDATE' button, There is  validation failed pop up.

The error is:

> Couldn’t fetch the page
> https://example.org/

Using the inspect URL I see no problem with both URLs. I also submitted an index request for both versions. All URLs are redirected with 301 status code.

Comment: I have submitted a question on google support ([here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/108595953/change-of-address-tool-couldn-t-fetch-the-page-error?hl=en)) but no one answered me there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After about one month without any related action from us the error was gone.